# 'Department' object is not iterable in Django?

Tags: python, django

I coundn't find the mistakes here. Department's objects and Year's objects are already created inside admin panel. So the field `department` and `years` in `ClassForm` should be rendered as `CharField` with **choices**. Why when I submitted the form I got the error?

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Year(models.Model):
    department = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    years = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Class(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey("account.CustomUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    years = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

# forms.py
class ClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ['department', 'years', 'subject']

#view.py
def createClassView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = app_forms.ClassForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'success': True}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': form.errors}, status=400)
    return HttpResponse("Class Create View")
```

error I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/attendance/app/views.py", line 63, in createClassView
    form.save()
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 461, in save
    self._save_m2m()
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 443, in _save_m2m
    f.save_form_data(self.instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1670, in save_form_data
    getattr(instance, self.attname).set(data)
  File "/Users/muongkimhong/Developments/itc-attendance/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 992, in set
    objs = tuple(objs)
TypeError: 'Department' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Maybe you can find solution here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476425/object-is-not-iterable-django-modelform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can pass `instance=request.user` to the form like code above. I have to do this:

```
form = app_forms.ClassForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
   form = form.save(commit=False)
   form.teacher = request.user
   form.save()
```